# gradle build is failed due to missing file

Tags: android

I wanted enable autocompletion when editing layout in android studio 2.3.3 ,so i deleted .idea folder and .iml files inside my project directory and i maked caches invalidated by navigating to Files> Invaliate Caches/restart..., but I encounter another problem when gradle build my project , that's my errors in Event Log:

```
28/07/2017
21:56   Gradle sync started

21:56   Platform and Plugin Updates: The following components are ready to update: Android Emulator, Google Play services, Google Repository, Android SDK Platform 26, Google APIs ARM 64 v8a System Image, Google APIs ARM EABI v7a System Image, Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image, Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image

21:56   FileNotFoundException: Entry fileTemplates//code/Google Test Fixture SetUp Method.cc.ft not found in C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/lib/idea.jar

21:56   Gradle sync completed

21:56   Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]

21:56   Gradle build finished with 3 error(s) in 4s 181ms

22:19   Enable smart keyboard internationalization for Studio.: We have found out that you are using a non-english keyboard layout. You can enable smart layout support for français language.You can change this option in the settings of Studio more...
```

that's my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.andoid.sunshine.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

In advance thank you for solving my problem

Comment: You should post both gradle files content, otherwise it's difficult to understand what's going on

Comment: For Android O support, you should be using Android Studio 3.0, currently on the canary channel.

Comment: @ephemient , but how you can explain that this problem is occured just when i Invalidate Caches and restart android studio.

Answer (score 0):

When 64 bit version of android studio is installed on a 32 bit machine, this issue may occur.  Refer [this](http://android.2317887.n4.nabble.com/Error-Android-Studio-2-3-3-FileNotFoundException-Entry-fileTemplates-code-Google-Test-Fixture-td430490.html) for more clarification.

- Uninstall your 64 bit android studio and install [32 bit version](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/2.3.3.0/android-studio-ide-162.4069837-windows32.zip) of the same.

Comment: I'm fairly sure I already have the 32 bit version, but am still getting the same Exception. How would I check to be sure? What other possible reasons and solutions might there be for this?